# parsing expression trees with booleans

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I am trying to parse an expression tree for a linq provider and running into a little snag with booleans.

I can parse this no problems.

```
var p = products.Where(x=>x.IsAvailable == true).ToList();
```

however when its written like this?

```
var p = products.Where(x=>x.IsAvailable).ToList();
```

i only get a MemberAccess to look at and i can't see how i deduce that it is true or false (!x.IsAvailable). Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps,

The first one has expression tree as shown below.

```
RETURN ( Binary Expression (MemberAccess, Constant) )
```

The second one has expression tree as shown below.

```
RETURN ( MemberAccess )
```

Since member is of type boolean, its value determines the state of execution.